# how to execute 2 newman tasks in parallely using jenkins.?

Tags: jenkins

```
How to Execute  this below code in paralley.. please help iam new to jenkins.

parallel firstBranch: {
node{
    newman run xyz.json
    }
},
secondBranch:{
    node{
      newman run xyz123.json
    }

}
},
failFast: true|false
```

for this i am gettig below error:
Also:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.cancel(CpsBodyExecution.java:244)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.BodyExecution.cancel(BodyExecution.java:76)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStepExecution.stop(ParallelStepExecution.java:67)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep$ResultHandler$Callback.checkAllDone(ParallelStep.java:147)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep$ResultHandler$Callback.onFailure(ParallelStep.java:134)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$FailureAdapter.receive(CpsBodyExecution.java:349)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ThrowBlock$1.receive(ThrowBlock.java:68)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the Jenkins documentaiton exemple click in the link bellow :

[Parallel stages with Declarative Pipeline 1.2](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)

to use new man with jenkins it's very easy

1. install nodeJS and npm
2. install newman by `npm install -g newman
3. create json file  newman-test:
   `{
   "name": "postman-newman-jenkins",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "Project postman test",
   "directories": {
   "test": "tests"
   },
   "scripts": {
   "api-tests-production": "newman run postman_collection.json --reporters cli,html --reporter-html-export ${Environment}-$BUILD_NUMBER-newman.html --reporter-html-template template.hbs
   },
   "author": "me or you",
   "dependencies": {
   "newman": "^3.5.2"
   }
   }`
4. in you jenkins

   ```
    try {

             sh 'npm install'
             sh 'npm run newman-test'

    }
             catch (Exception err) {
                 currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
     }
   ```
5. to archive your report

   archiveArtifacts 'jenkins/${Environment}-$BUILD_NUMBER-newman.html'

in the last you can format this code to respect declarative pipeline code

Comment: thank you for replaying ... i want to run newman code. it is not working in pipeline ..i need code for that .please help me

Comment: for me it works in simple pipeline not declarative pipeline (i don't tried it)